# How to write this JavaScript code without eval?

Tags: javascript, eval

How to write this JavaScript code without eval?

```
var typeOfString = eval("typeof " + that.modules[modName].varName);
if (typeOfString !== "undefined") {
  doSomething();
}
```

The point is that the name of the var that I want to check for is in a string.

Maybe it is simple but I don't know how.

*Edit:* Thank you for the very interesting answers so far. I will follow your suggestions and integrate this into my code and do some testing and report. Could take a while.

*Edit2:* I had another look at the could and maybe itis better I show you a bigger picture. I am greatful for the experts to explain so beautiful, it is better with more code:

```
MYNAMESPACE.Loader = ( function() {

  function C() {
    this.modules = {};
    this.required = {};
    this.waitCount = 0;
    this.appendUrl = '';
    this.docHead = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  }

  function insert() {
    var that = this;
    //insert all script tags to the head now!
    //loop over all modules:
    for (var modName in this.required) {
      if(this.required.hasOwnProperty(modName)){
        if (this.required[modName] === 'required') {
          this.required[modName] = 'loading';
          this.waitCount = this.waitCount + 1;
          this.insertModule(modName);
        }
      }
    }

    //now poll until everything is loaded or 
    //until timout

    this.intervalId = 0;

    var checkFunction = function() {
      if (that.waitCount === 0) {
        clearInterval(that.intervalId);
        that.onSuccess();
        return;
      }
      for (var modName in that.required) {
        if(that.required.hasOwnProperty(modName)){
          if (that.required[modName] === 'loading') {
            var typeOfString = eval("typeof " + that.modules[modName].varName);
            if (typeOfString !== "undefined") {
              //module is loaded!
              that.required[modName] = 'ok';
              that.waitCount = that.waitCount - 1; 
              if (that.waitCount === 0) {
                clearInterval(that.intervalId);
                that.onSuccess();
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    //execute the function twice a second to check if all is loaded:
    this.intervalId = setInterval(checkFunction, 500);
    //further execution will be in checkFunction,
    //so nothing left to do here
  }
  C.prototype.insert = insert;

  //there are more functions here...

  return C;
}());


var myLoader = new MYNAMESPACE.Loader();

//some more lines here... 

myLoader.insert();
```

*Edit3:*

I am planning to put this in the global namespace in variable MYNAMESPACE.loadCheck, for simplicity, so the result would be, combining from the different answers and comments:

```
if (MYNAMESPACE.loadCheck.modules[modName].varName in window) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Of course I will have to update the Loader class where ever "varName" is mentioned.

Comment: What is the problem with just doing typeof that.modules[modName].varName ? Can you post your whole code.

Comment: @Alexandre: it is code from a function of a loader class. So "that" refers to an instance of the class. The code is within a function of the class.

Comment: @Ivo: This is a whole class, I feel it's not adequate to post all the code. Sorry, I did not take the time to really reduce the code to just isolate the problem. But some posters seem to give solutions already. To answer your first questions: it is not a problem. I just wonder how to do it. I will report later and also paste more code then.

Comment: So you have a loader class and you want to check if some global variables have been imported by the loaded scripts. `modName` is the name of your module (loaded script) and `varName` is the name of the global variable that the script creates in the global object (`window`).

Comment: In the meantime I posted more code. There is class Loader with a function that has a callback function (using intervals) and it is in the callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in JS every variable is a property, if you have no idea whose property it is, it's a `window` property, so I suppose, in your case, this could work:

```
var typeOFString = typeof window[that.modules[modName].varName]
if (typeOFString !== "undefined") {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: otherwise (that is, if you're using the javascript `with(object) {...}` or you're in a *function scope*) you're supposed to search all the objects that could contain it, in sequence.

Comment: fyi you could use "this" rather than "window"

Comment: javascript function variables, IIRC, are function properties, so if you're doing: `function x() {var a=10;}` you will have to check for `varName='a'; typeof x[varName];`

Comment: `this` makes no sense here, if we're talking about variables and not properties of arbitrary objects. It would still work for plain function calls where `this===window`, but why would you do that?

Comment: `typeof x[varName]` makes no sense here either, we are not talking about a function property.

Comment: Only global variables are properties of the global object. In other contexts, variables are **not** properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only testing for the *existence* of the item, you can use `in` rather than `typeof`.

So for global variables as per ZJR's answer, you can look for them on the `window` object:

```
if (that.modules[modName].varName in window) {
    ...
}
```

If you need to look for local variables there's no way to do that without `eval`. But this would be a sign of a serious misdesign further up the line.

Comment: It's not exactly the same test. If the variable was declared but its value was _undefined_, then typeof would return "undefined", but in window would return true.

Comment: @Alsciende I can see the difference. In the case of this class it would not matter.